# Use formula to pull identity from one field to another

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select

I have a field in a mysql table that stores events in JSON. This JSON has inside it the ID of a file that the event is about. Is there a way to have another field auto-populate with that file ID? Something like a formula field in Excel? Format inside the JSON is `"item_id": "1234567"`

New to SQL so help is appreciated. :)

Example JSON in column "event":

> {"video_proc_producer_ver": 2,"mp_event":{"project_name": "some
>   project","project_account": "some customer","mp_notes": "No playable
>   combo ids found for item_id: 1234abcd.\\n\n","item_name":
>   "file.mov","mp_m_stamp": "2020-03-09 02:27:50","mp_c_stamp":
>   "2020-03-09 02:22:14","mp_processing_mask": "4","c_user_id":
>   "123456","mp_export_time": "2020-03-09 02:24:22",**"item_id":
>   "0987654"**,"project_id": "1234","mp_complete_time": "2020-03-09
>   02:27:50"}}

result in column `file_id: 0987654`

I know I can use some process outside the table to pull that info and insert it, but I was wondering if there is the equivalent of a calculated column like in except that I can use inside the table to have that auto-populate. If so, what kind of column do I need to create and what formula would I use?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to access the content of the json object. In MySQL, you can use `json_extract()`, or the `->>` operator, like so:

```
select event, event ->> '$.mp_event.item_id' file_id from mytable
```